# How to make piwik track ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, matomo

I wonder how I can make piwik track ajax requests. There is an API, but I don't understand what I must do exactly, to see ajax loaded pages in the dashboard.

perhaps this:

```
_paq.push([ 'API_method_name', parameter_list ]);
```

Where should I place this (globally or for every ajax call) and what are the right `API_method_name` and `parameter_list`?

Thanks for help

Comment: [Ajax Requests with Piwik](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.archive.org%2Fweb%2F20160207105517%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.fredyy.de%2Fblog%2F2010%2F11%2Fajax-requests-mit-piwik)

Answer (score 1):

I found [Event Tracking](http://piwik.org/docs/event-tracking/#tracking-events).

```
_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Photo Viewer', href]);
```

Which I call in my ajax function. It shows arrows in the dashboard.

[image: piwik event tracking symbols]

Answer (score 0):

For those who are a bit newer at web development,
here's the detailed explanation:

Add the piwik tracking code to the page head as usual,
then add the following in the html  link which loads the ajax content:

```
onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'NavMenu', 'CV']);"
```

So, the full ajax link that you wish to track, in context might look like this:

```
<li class="cv"><a href="./main/cv.html" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'NavMenu', 'CV']);">CV</a></li>
```

"NavMenu" and "CV" should be changed according to your links & preferences.